# Integration of hypergeometric functions?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, harmonic-analysis, hypergeometric-function

I would calculate the following integral
\begin{equation}
I_x  = \int_{0}^{1} y^{b+\mu-1} (1-y)^{\nu-1}\, _2F_1(a,b+\nu +\mu;c; xy) \, dy.
\end{equation}
Such that $\quad \Re a,\Re b,\Re \mu, \Re \nu >0$ and $ -1<x<1$.

Someone can help me!!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is the following:
\begin{align}
I_{x} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{n} \, (b+\nu + \mu)_{n}}{n! \, (c)_{n}} \, x^{n} \, J_{n}
\end{align}
where 
$$J_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} y^{n + b + \mu -1} \, (1-y)^{\nu-1} \, dy.$$
Now,
\begin{align}
J_{n} &= B(n + b + \mu, \nu) = B(b+\mu, \nu) \, \frac{(b+\mu)_{n}}{(b+\mu + \nu)_{n}}
\end{align}
and leads to
\begin{align}
I_{x} &= B(b+\mu, \nu) \, {}_{2}F_{1}(a, b+\mu; c; x), 
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} y^{b+ \mu -1} \, (1-y)^{\nu -1} \, {}_{2}F_{1}(a, b + \nu + \mu; c; xy) \, dy = B(b+\mu, \nu) \, {}_{2}F_{1}(a, b+\mu; c; x).
\end{align}

Comment: @ Leucippus, thanks for your answer